# How do I disable the colored marks that appear next to changed lines when using git?

Tags: git, prelude, fringe

I am using orgmode and after I put my files under git I see some lines that appear next to lines that have changed. They are red, green or blue.

I would like to disable this but have no idea how they are called.

[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/V1wZ7.png]

Comment: Sounds like you are using git-gutter https://github.com/syohex/emacs-git-gutter

Comment: i am not. maybe something else?

Comment: Maybe somebody would recognize it if you posted a screenshot?

Comment: Is it `hl-diff`?

Comment: no. i dont have that command available

Comment: Press `M-x describe-mode RET` and look in the help buffer to see what minor modes are active, along with the major mode -- those will likely give you a clue as to what is causing the bitmap images to be displayed in the left fringe.  In terms of starting with a flow-blown configuration such as prelude, there will undoubtedly be a plethora of stuff that isn't normally active by default but is nevertheless set by the prelude package -- such that it will take a long time before you become familiar with all the non-default settings.

Comment: Looks like https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl#diff-hl-mode

Comment: @JasonMirk Ah, I had the `hl` and `diff` the other way around in my comment :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The highlighting is performed by `diff-hl-mode` from the [diff-hl](https://github.com/dgutov/diff-hl) package, and can be toggled with `M-x diff-hl-mode`, or unconditionally disabled by passing a negative argument (`M-- M-x diff-hl-mode` interactively, `(diff-hl-mode -1)` from lisp) [like most minor modes](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Minor-Modes.html).

---

To find out yourself which minor mode is causing the effect you could use <kbd>f1 m</kbd> (`describe-mode`) and look in the help buffer to see what minor modes are active, along with the major mode -- those will likely give you a clue as to what is causing the bitmap images to be displayed in the left fringe.

The [`manage-minor-mode`](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/manage-minor-mode) package could also be helpful to debug cases like these.

Comment: It would also be helpful to suggest how the OP could have figured this out by himself.. by reviewing which minor modes are active and disabling them one by one. [`manage-minor-mode`](https://github.com/ShingoFukuyama/manage-minor-mode) package could turn out to be helpful to debug cases like these.

Comment: @lawlist & kaushalmodi: I've added your comments to the answer and made it community wiki so feel free to edit it as you like.